# if condition is not working - python program

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to write progarm, The function accepts two integers n, m as arguments Find the sum of all numbers in range from 1 to m(both inclusive) that are not divisible by n. Return difference between sum of integers not divisible by n with the sum of numbers divisible by n.
In my case, if is not working.

```
n = int(input("num "))
m = int(input("limit "))
for i in range(1, m+1):
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    if i % n == 0:
        sum1 += i
    else:
        sum2 += i
print(f"{sum1} and {sum2}")
print(abs(sum2-sum1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `sum1 = 0` and `sum2 = 0` *outside* the for loop; currently you are resetting those values at each iteration, so that it does not keep the sum.

```py
n, m = 2, 10
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
for i in range(1, m+1):
    if i % n == 0:
        sum1 += i
    else:
        sum2 += i
print(f"{sum1} and {sum2}")
print(abs(sum2-sum1))
```

Output:

```
30 and 25
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring your sum1 and sum2 outside of the loop, you're resetting them every time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
not_n = []
with_n = []
def inputts(n, m):
# code
    for x in range(1, m+1):
        if x % n == 0:
            with_n.append(x)
        else:
           not_n.append(x)
# now sum
    nott_n = sum(not_n)
    withh_n = sum(with_n)
    

#now substraction
    subb=(withh_n-nott_n)
    print(abs(subb))

inputts(5,100)
```